# Quicksort does not work with large arrays

Tags: c++, eclipse, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I'm trying to sort large arrays with Quicksort and Mergesort to evaluate performances.

I've a problem: if I impose a large number of elements in an array, the program does not start to generate values randomly. In the code below, if `N=500000`, it works very well. If `N > 500000`, for example `1000000`, it does not work. With MergeSort the limit is `200000`. I tried on multiple devices, C++ on Eclipse IDE.

Someone knows how to solve the problem?

```
#define N 800000
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void Exchange(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int Partition(int A[], int p, int r) {
     int x = A[r];
     int i = p - 1;
     for (int j = p; j <= r; j++) {
         if (A[j] < x) {
             i++;
             Exchange(&A[i], &A[j]);
         }

    }
    Exchange(&A[i + 1], &A[r]);
    return i + 1;
}

int RPartition(int A[], int p, int r) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = p + rand() % (p - r);
    Exchange(&A[i], &A[r]);
    return Partition(A, p, r);
}

void QuickSort(int A[], int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = RPartition(A, p, r);
        QuickSort(A, p, q - 1);
        QuickSort(A, q + 1, r);
    }
}

void Stampa(int A[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << A[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(50000);
    int A[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = rand();
    }

    cout << "Array non ordinato\n";
    Stampa(A, N);
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    QuickSort(A, 0, N - 1);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    cout << "\nArray ordinato\n";
    Stampa(A, N);
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;
    cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << "s";
}
```

Comment: You may be running out of *stack* space.  Try declaring the array as static or moving it outside of `main()`.

Comment: just use `std::vector` instead C-array as it should be done from begging.

Comment: If this isn't some sort of assignment, consider using `std::vector` and `std::sort`.

Comment: definitely running out of stack space, 500K integers requires 8MB of memory which just happens to be the default stack size on Linux and Mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack/heap overflow when declaring a large array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617794/stack-heap-overflow-when-declaring-a-large-array)

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` does *not* belong in *any* repetition-called code, and in your case, that means `RPartition`. Remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is very simple: you allocate the array as a local variable with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*), hence if the size is too large, you get a *stack overflow*.

You should either allocate the array from the heap or define it as static data.

Here is a modified version:

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int *A = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        A[i] = rand();
    }

    cout << "Array non ordinato\n";
    Stampa(A, N);

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    QuickSort(A, 0, N - 1);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    cout << "\nArray ordinato\n";
    Stampa(A, N);

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;
    cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << "s";
    delete[] A;
}
```